# Redis-RB out of the box throwing ECONNREFUSED error on local

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I added `gem 'redis'` to my Gemfile. Ran `bundle install`. Restarted the local server, then ran the hello world example in my console only to get an error. Any idea what's wrong?

```
[kudo (develop)]$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p125 :001 > redis = Redis.new
=> #<Redis client v3.0.2 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0> 
1.9.3p125 :002 > redis.set("mykey", "hello world")
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:268:in `rescue in establish_connection'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:69:in `connect'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:282:in `ensure_connected'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:173:in `block in process'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `logging'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:172:in `process'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:608:in `block in set'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis.rb:607:in `set'
from (irb):2
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/pejman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3p125 :003 >
```

Comment: Doing some more digging around looks like this just installs the client, but not the server. That's a separate process. Will update when I get that up and running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up being pretty simple.

To install redis (server) I ran (in the terminal):

```
brew install redis
```

Then in a separate terminal window, I started the server with:

```
redis-server
```

Now I'm all setup. My redis.set command works fine now in the rails console.

Here's a good resource I found that walks through it more in depth: http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: Just a note that I need to specify the config file to run redis-server from the terminal. This may differ for your setup, but seems like this is the most common path for Mac OS X: `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`